# How to make horizontally scrollable multi-line chipgroup in android?

Tags: android, xml, multiline, horizontal-scrolling, android-chips

Horizontally scrollable multi-line chip group

[image]

This is the chip group design I am trying to make in android. I have tried to use three chip-groups for three lines but they don't scroll together. Please suggest a solution, preferably without using any extra library.

Comment: Have you looked into [asymmetrical grid layout](https://medium.com/android-news/asymmetrical-grid-layout-using-recyclerview-5ed44899d7b5)

Comment: Nope. Actually heard of it for the first time. Will check documentation.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to implement this using RecyclerView then simply put

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager"
```

and your final recycler view code is

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:spanCount="3"
    tools:itemCount="20"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item" />
```